# Angular 2 routing with Visual Studio & .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, angular

I completed the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on Angular 2's website and everything is working great. If I click around, the URL changes and when I refresh, it takes me right where I was before, as you would expect with proper routing.

I want to now use .NET and C# on the backend, so I went through Angular 2's tutorial on getting the project set up with Visual Studio (I was using Sublime Text before). I completed it and got it working, but noticed that the routing only worked when pressing the back/forward buttons. Refreshing didn't work like it did when I just used Sublime and NPM. I went back to the tutorial and found a message at the bottom that concerns me:

"If this application used the Angular router, a browser refresh could return a 404 - Page Not Found. Look at the address bar. Does it contain a navigation url (a "deep link")? We'll have to configure the server to return index.html for these requests. Until we do, remove the navigation path and refresh again."
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html#!#build-and-run

Does this mean that Angular 2's routing won't work with Visual Studio when I refresh the page no matter what? Is there no hope for Angular 2's routing to fully work when using Visual Studio/.NET/C#?

Comment: Refer this article- http://www.centare.com/tutorial-angular2-mvc-6-asp-net-5/ This is little old article but angular2 routing works perfectly fine within ASP.NET core application.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a look. Good to know I can get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular 2 uses the HTML5 history API. The urls look just like any other site. When you load http://example.com/posts/23 the .NET backend will try to handle it and if it can't will return 404.

That is not what you want.

You want to return the contents of index.html and let Angular handle the rest.

Note that you don't want to redirect to http://example.com/index.html, if you do that it will load angular but you will lose the current path. That way you will never be able to share links to your site.

I assume that you are using the latest version of .NET Core and Visual Studio's templates.

What you need to do:

- Install this NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`
- Go to `Startup.cs` and find the `Configure` method
- Add these lines before `app.UseMvc();`

  ```
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  ```
- Add these lines after `app.UseMvc();`

  ```
  app.Run(async context =>
  {
      context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
      await context.Response.SendFileAsync("./wwwroot/index.html");
  });
  ```
- Add this to the top of the file

  ```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
  ```

For more information look here:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href

Comment: I'm inexperienced with .NET unfortunately. Is this something I would take care of in the RouteConfig.cs file? And how would I do the override?

Comment: I don't know if I'm using an older version of .NET or MVC, but I searched the entire project and there are no results found for app.UseMvc(

Comment: Can you give me the contents of your Startup.cs and project.json ?

Comment: I'm updating an existing .NET project, so I can't start from scratch.

Comment: I have a package.json for my Angular 2 stuff, is that what you mean? I searched and couldn't find a project.json file.

Comment: So it's an old .NET project. You have to edit your Web.config for that. Wait a few minutes to see what I can find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124583/discussion-between-hristokolev-and-brett).